# Date.getMonth() is an error after using Date.setMonth()

Tags: javascript, date

I currently working on flatpickr.js and try to set date for minimum date. This can simply be done by  `minDate: new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 4)`. However, this returns the current month - 4 and the current time. But I need to set the time to always be at `00:00:00` on whatever minimum date is.

**Trial**

`minDate: new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 4).setHours(0,0,0,0)`

```
var minDate = new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - minMonth);
    var minDate 1 = minDate.getFullYear() + minDate.getMonth()+ minDate.getDay()'
```

However, this return `getMonth is not a function` or `getFullYear is not a function`.
Can help me with this case?

Comment: 1. `.getFullYear`, `.getMonth` and `.getDay` are methods hence it should be `.getFullYear()`, ...; 2. [`.setMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) returns the number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the updated date. And a number has no `Date` methods like `.getFullYear()`

Comment: sorry my mistake, I wrote the code wrongly in question. I edited it. Please review the question again. Since that the case, is there any way to set the time to ```00:00:00``` after set the month?

Comment: The `.setX` methods modify the `Date` object in-place and return a number. Either pass its return value to the `Date` constructor to create a new `Date` object or just don't use its return value and therefor stop chaining `.setX` calls.

Comment: Great explanation @Andreas. Really help me understand this much better. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Date Object in the JavaScript can not allow chaining that allows us to perform multiple action on the object, all within a single line of code. This is not possible because set operation will not return an object.

```
var obj  = {
    minDate : (function(){
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth(0-4));
        dt.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        return dt;
    }())
}
```

Using the Date object often to converting into accessible object to perform chaining

```
new Date(new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 4)).setHours(0,0,0,0))
```

Comment: Creating 4 date objects just to use a single statement is very inefficient. Consider `let d = new Date(); d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 4); d.setHours(0,0,0,0);`. Note that if run on 30 Jun, this will return 1 or 2 March.

Comment: it's more verbose and less readable , I agree with your advice and updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, the method `setMonth` returns a timestamp, not the date object, and secondly, since `getFullYear` and other methods return number, adding them will add them as numbers, and will not concatenate them as strings which means you might want to do this instead:

```js
    var minMonth = 2;// any month number
    var minDate = new Date();
    minDate.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - minMonth);
    var minDateString = `${minDate.getFullYear()}${String(minDate.getMonth()).padStart(2, '0')}${String(minDate.getDay()).padStart(2, '0')}`;
    console.log(minDateString);
```

As you can see `padStart`can also help you to have the month and day in two digit format(`01` instead of `1`).